# prove this complex function $f$ is complex differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I have a complex function $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$ and I know both functions $u$ and $v$ are differentiable at some $z=z_0$.
Also I know the following limit exists:
                               $\lim\limits_{z\to z_0} \mathrm{arg} \left(\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0} \right)$.

How can I prove $f$ is complex differentiable at $z_0$?

I just have started learning complex analysis so I need a simple answer :)

Comment: Didn't you just ask this same question? I commented that I thought $f(z)=|z|^2$ was a counterexample, because it is differentiable at $0$, but the argument is identically zero ( since $f(z)$  is Real-valued, but Cauchy-Riemann does not hold in any open set about $0$

Comment: @BFD: $\arg f$ is constant, but $\arg(f(z)/z) = \arg \bar z$ is not. Also, there is a difference between being complex differentiable at a single point and being holomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cauchy-Riemann  Properties to prove that $f$ has complex differentiable at $z_0$.

set $z=x+iy$.

Then

Must have that $\frac {\partial u}{\partial x}(z_0)=\frac {\partial v}{\partial y}(z_0)$ and

$\frac {\partial u}{\partial y}(z_0)=-\frac {\partial v}{\partial x}(z_0)$.

Comment: But how do I prove those equations are true using the limit of arg?

Comment: $f(z)=|f(z)|e^{iarg(f(z))}$. Find the derivative of $f$ at $z_0$ by this form

Comment: Thanks for all the help but I still don't understand something...
Do I need to directly calculate the derivative from the limit definition or prove that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are true?

Comment: prove that the C-R  are true

Comment: And how do I do that?

I proved that $arg(u_x+i\cdot v_x)=arg(v_y-i\cdot u_y)$ but I don't know how to continue from here...

Comment: Sorry mate,i thought that you know the types of$ u,v$. Ok. Because $u,v$ are differentiable at $z_0$ we have that $f$ is continuous at $z_0$ so no problem. We have that $\frac {f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$ =$|\frac {f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}|$$e^{iarg(\frac   {f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0})}$. From here we have that $\lim\limits_{z\to z_0} \frac {f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$ exists

Comment: I tried proving that $\lim_{z->z_0}\left | \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0} \right |$ exists but I got stuck. I would be happy if you could give me a clue to how to prove the existence of this limit.